# The most general notion is the intersection of an arbitrary nonempty collection of sets.

Tags: analysis

The most general notion is the intersection of an arbitrary nonempty collection of sets. If M is a nonempty set whose elements are themselves sets, then x is an element of the intersection of M if and only if for every element A of M, x is an element of A.
My question is: What is themselves sets? Can anyone give an example of this? Thank you.

Comment: $x\in\bigcap\mathcal M\iff x\in m$ for every $m\in\mathcal M$. For that to be true the elements of $\mathcal M$ must be (themselves) sets. If e.g. $\mathcal M=\{A,B\}$ where $A$ and $B$ are sets then $x\in\bigcap\mathcal M\iff x\in A$ and $x\in B$, or equivalently $x\in\bigcap\mathcal M\iff x\in A\cap B$. Apparantly $\bigcap\{A,B\}=A\cap B$.

Comment: Thank you so much!